# google area chart with negative numbers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I'm using Google Stacked Area Chart in ASP.NET MVC app.

The question is can this chart make stacked areas with negative values (for example, from -20 to -10, from -10 to 10, from 10 to 30,...)?
If that's impossible, is there any chart tool for ASP.NET MVC to complete this task?

Comment: saygılar köksal baba

Comment: Baba stacking yapiyosan olmaz. ama tek stack takiliyorsan `baseline: 0` cek vertical domainin dibine insen negatifim diyemez sana! tekrar saygilar baba

Comment: Unfortunately, i'm not turkish =) Thank you, i'll make a try.

Comment: well in that case please accept our deepest respect offering father "rootrelease" :)